# C++ polymorphism: Why is static binding impossible even when the type is obvious

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, late-binding

I am learning about virtual functions and virtual tables in C++. But, I could not understand why there is a need for dynamic binding. Doesn't the compiler have all the information to figure out if the function call is for the derived or the base function, for example here:

```
class Base1 { 
   public : virtual void foo() 
            {  cout << " Base foo \n"; } 
};

class Base2 {
   public : virtual void foo() 
           { cout << " Base2 foo \n"; } 
};

class derived : public base1, base 2 {
     public : virtual void foo() 
       { cout << " derived foo \n"; }
}

int main()
{
  derived d;
  Base2 *p = &d;
  p->foo();       // why can't the compiler figure out that this
                  // is a function call to the derived function
                  // foo at compile time?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, yes, and some compilers may optimize away the virtual call with simple flow analysis, but in general, you can pass `p` anywhere (including to functions that are in different translation units) and there's no way for them to know how `p` was initialized. Even within the same translation unit, you could easily write a program in which determining the runtime type of `*p` is halting-problem-complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why cant compile figure that this is a function call to derived function foo during compile runtime itself?

It can.  And some compilers *will* convert that call to static binding.

And there are other scenarios when the compiler **must use dynamic binding**.

Which `foo()` should get called in this function?

```
void function( Base* p )
{
  p->foo();
}
```

It can't be determined*.  Dynamic binding must be used.

*Edit: Based on the information I've given.  :)

Comment: Well, it possibly could be, with interprocedural flow analysis...there's lots of ways of devirtualizing calls if you really want to :)